# date field in php is returning wrong value

Tags: php

Am trying to get the date selected from a FORM to my sql database using php.

Code for JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools-core-1.4.5-full-compat.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        new DatePicker('.picker', {
         pickerClass: 'datepicker ',
             allowEmpty: true
                     });           
</script>
```

Code for Date field in the FORM - HTML

```
 <td><input name='DateOfJourney' type='text' value='' class='date picker' ></td>
```

Code for PHP which i am echoing:
    `echo $_POST['DateOfJourney'];`

Also the DateOfJourney field in the sql table is VARCHAR type.

There are codes for CSS, if needed i'll copy them. The date field in the form is a date picker format.

When selecting the date as `16-02-2013`, the output its throwing is : `1361079469` which is a junk it seems.

Can you let me know how to get the exact value which i put in input in the FORM to reflect the same in the output database?

Comment: What you think as junk might be the milliseconds (some form of timestamp) please double check

Answer (score 2):

That value is not `junk`, it is UNIX Timestamp for your date. Try this

```
<?php
echo date("m-d-Y",1361079469);    // or use `d-m-Y` as Rikesh suggested below
echo date("m-d-Y",$_POST['DateOfJourney']);
?>
```

Comment: May be user wants in `d-m-Y` :) Or he will found this junk too :p

Comment: That worked, i used the above code:
    `echo date("m-d-Y",$_POST['DateOfJourney']);`

But it is echoing DateOfJourney+1.
Also, how to insert this date to sql database?